# Replacing some JS lines with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form below which uses javascript to perfom a maths equation.  But i want the equation hidden, so that means replacing the JS maths equation line (var result), with a new php script.  I am thinking the php code should be outside of the JS tags, perhaps using the JS variables.  But i dont know much about php.  I am not trying to learn php, i am just trying to get a working form, so please no convoluted lessons on how php works.  I want to avoid using node js and doing ajax calls etc. If not possible please say so.

```html
<html>
    <head>
<script>
function bmi ()  {
var height = Number(document.getElementById("height").value);
var weight = Number(document.getElementById("weight").value);
var result = weight / (height * height);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Your score is : " + result;
}
</script>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <h4>BMI</h4>
            <input id="height" type="text" placeholder="height in meters or feet" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input id="weight" type="text" placeholder="weight in kgs or lbs" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input class = "submit" type="button"  value="Submit" onclick="bmi()" />
            <p id="result">Result</p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not possible if you want the results in the same page :) (without ajax)

Comment: Using jquery for this task and a server side php script would be trivial. Not much learning involved. But it does use ajax, which is the only way to embed php into an active page that has already been delivered by the server to the client.

Comment: You would need to use a traditional POSTBACK, where the form posts the request back to the server, which performs a calculation if those request parameters are set and puts it's outcome in the response. Without Javascript, you can't do it without a page refresh.

Comment: I found something like this below, which seems to execute php code on js variables.  Ive tried it and it works in the sense that the php code is hidden from the client side which is what i want:

<script type="text/javascript">
function test()
{
    var pt = 3;
    document.write('<?php add("'+pt+'");?>');
}

test();
</script>

<?php

function add($param)
{
    echo $param;
}  
?>

Comment: That will write `<?php add("3");?>` on the screen literally, without passing to PHP. The problem with your idea is, that PHP is on the server, but JS is in the browser (client), so it's impossible to involve PHP in JS operations without making a new request from the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function bmi($height, $weight) {
    $height = floatval($height);
    $weight = floatval($weight);
    return $weight / ($height * $height);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <h4>BMI</h4>
    <input id="height" name="height" type="text" placeholder="height in meters or feet" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['height']) ? $_POST['height'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input id="weight" name="weight" type="text" placeholder="weight in kgs or lbs" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['weight']) ? $_POST['weight'] : ''; ?>" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <?php if (!empty($_POST['height']) && !empty($_POST['weight'])) : ?>
    <p>Your score is <?php echo bmi($_POST['height'], $_POST['weight']); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this does produce a working form.  I guess i was trying to keep some of the form in JS and only the result in php, but may have to go this route of using just php

Answer (score 0):

Without AJAX call, its not possible i guess if u want to use php. 
Another way is, you can use angular to get your problem's solution.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give an example using ajax call?